# How to track out going call events/states from android?

Tags: android, call

i am working on out going calls. 
i can track event when call button is pressed, but i cannot track event when ring goes to other person or call has been received by other person. 
Is there a way to track these events???

Comment: You can use broadcast receiver to track call state.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
public class PhListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();

    if (bundle == null)
        return;

    String s = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (i.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
        String number = i.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

    }else if (s.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        String number = bundle.getString("incoming_number");

    }else if (s.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

    }else if (s.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

    }

}
```

And in Manifest declare

```
    <receiver android:name="com.android.receiver.PhListener" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-1" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```